# Tinnitus Masking with broadband Noise

Tags: noise

I have the problem of masking tinnitus. I have the following questions:

1. Can broadband noise mask tone tinnitus, or any kind of tinnitus (such as narrowband, or chirp)?
2. Assume an audiogram test has identified tinnitus as tonal with loudness level of $x$ dB and  frequency/pitch of $y$ Hz. How can I create broadband noise  using this information (note that we don't know the variance of the noise)? How could this be implemented in Matlab?

Thanks.

sedy

Comment: actually, for me, it seems that broadband "noise" seems to set off the tinnitus.  like if i am in a room that is silent, it often remains silent.  but if i am out in the woods and i can hear low-level background sounds (from distant traffic to nearby birds), it seems like these low-level sounds have to compete with the noisy tinnitus.  perhaps this is just the character of my hearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [tinnitus masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinnitus_masker) on Wiki. Yes, you can mask it with various kinds of noise and/or natural sounds that are "noisy" (ocean, rainfall, etc)

For the synthesis of masking noise, there is plenty of information via google & StackOverflow. Keep in mind that broadband noise (versus bandlimited noise) is present *across* the spectrum and thus, you only need to be approximately in the same [bark frequency band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bark_scale) of the tone you want to mask.

Here is a plot showing one measurement of Tinnitus spectrum (from http://www.thelancet.com/cms/attachment/2021743353/2041580240/gr1.jpg). I wasn't able to access the [full thelancet article](http://www.thelancet.com/journals/laneur/article/PIIS1474-4422(13)70160-1/fulltext?version=printerFriendly):

[image]

Comment: Hi Ruoho,   I cannot be using truly broadband noise, but limit it to critical frequency band, but is it possible to obtain spectrum of tinnitus from audiogram?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a diagram, to show the location of Tinnitus pitch on an audiogram

Comment: @ Ruoho I am new to audiometery..can you point me to source where you found above picture? Also, as per my first question, if I know my tinnitus tone is at "x" db which may be "y" in linear scale, can i assume that y^2 would be the power that I need and so i create white noise of Power spectral density = y1^2, and pass it through Filter with bandwidth DelF so that y^2 = y1^2 * DelF?

Comment: Okay, I added the link: http://www.thelancet.com/cms/attachment/2021743353/2041580240/gr1.jpg I wasn't able to access the full article for free. And yes, if you convert from dB to linear, the power is the square (^2), and you'll want to have a filtered (band-passed) noise with wide-enough bandwidth to mask.

Comment: @ Ruoho Thanks for reply. Can you give the link of the article. I can get it downloaded

Comment: I linked it in the response, also here: http://www.thelancet.com/journals/laneur/article/PIIS1474-4422(13)70160-1/fulltext?version=printerFriendly Don't forget to mark your question as answered. Cheers.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?rq=1